# Trouble with POST request whith angular and SpringBoot

Tags: angular, spring, rest

Trouble witn POST request. I have 5 fields with time: 4 writes a user(works well), 1 is set through the system time(trouble).
Problem field initializing (time):

```
todayDate: Date = new Date(Date.now()); // call time and date    
    this.callForm.patchValue({
            date: [formatDate(this.todayDate,"yyyy-MM-dd",'en' )], // set value field date of fieldControl
            time: [formatDate(this.todayDate,"HH:mm",'en' )] //  // set value field time of fieldControl
          })
```

When user set values to field time, POST request works well, when time sets by a function i get error in spring boot:

```
2020-08-18 12:06:25.443  WARN 5340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : 

Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.Date` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.Date` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 22] (through reference chain: com.kiryushin.pspmonitoring.entity.Calls["time"])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.callForm.patchValue({
date: formatDate(this.todayDate,"yyyy-MM-dd",'en' ),
time: formatDate(this.todayDate,"HH:mm",'en' )
})

You can debug your code  why its not working by using function when it works when user gives input is just to compare result before sending it to API

Comment: You're right, it works. I was comparing all solutions with a working method (ex: print "time" with console.log command). Any of my methods outputs the same values ​​as the worker. You can tell what the problem is, maybe send reference to documentation?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The code above is lost. Mamta's working code is below:

```
 this.callForm.patchValue({
    date: formatDate(this.todayDate,"yyyy-MM-dd",'en' ),
    time: formatDate(this.todayDate,"HH:mm",'en' )
  })
```